# mvc 3 remote validation not firing

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0

I am attempting to use the remote data annotation for the first time in MVC 3. 
I am missing something simple.   The setup is not firing the controller action at all and I'm not seeing the issue off hand.

I am attempting to validate username for uniqueness.

Here is the code setup.

View Code

```
@Html.Raw(Html.Script("jquery.validate.min.js"))
@Html.Raw(Html.Script("jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"))

<tr>
            <td class="editor-label">@Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserName):</td>
            <td  class="editor-field">@Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserName)</td>
            <td>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserName)</td>
        </tr>
```

ViewModel Code

```
    [DisplayName("Username")]
    [StringLength(100)]
    [Remote("CheckIfUsernameExists", "UserProfile", ErrorMessage = "This username is taken. Please enter a different user name.")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }
```

Controller Code

```
[HttpGet]
        public JsonResult CheckIfUsernameExists(string userName)
        {
            return Json("false");
        }
```

Comment: is the client validation firing for the string length?

Comment: You can find other options on: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37366502/4146766

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check you setting, the client validation and the unobtrusive should be enabled

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
```

with that the following code should work

```
    [Get]
    public JsonResult CheckIfUsernameExists(string userName)
    {
        return Json(false,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Comment: i had 2 viewmodels in the same .cs file and had the dataannotation in the wrong viewmodel.  Code is working as expected now, thanks.